# Technologies needed for building website like this

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, web-applications, portfolio

I am planning to create my portfolio site. There are so many options, from static website generator to latest SPA. I have always been back-end developer and never had to do website development.

I want my portfolio to look like this: http://hackberrylab.com/

What are the technologies needed to build a SPA like this, exactly like this. Or can I download this website and simply change the content?

As per my research, `AngularJS` is one of the way to go ahead for SPA, there are many tutorials as well. But none of them produces an example like this site. I don't mind learning multiple technologies as well, it will rather be fun.

Pl guide.

Comment: angularjs could help you here, but so could jquery.  I would use angularjs, but i'm a bit biased.

Comment: is there any tutorial which generates output like this webapp?

Comment: It's a **parallax** website

Comment: You most likely need to know how to accomplish it using pure javascript first. AngularJS would just help you organize your code better (i.e. into re-usable modules).  AngularJS by itself would not be enough to build a site like that. You need to know how to produce the effects on that web page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to go with custom solution rather looking for already built solution. 
Technologies that I can suggest might be new to you. but once you start following technologies, they'd help you to grow in any future projects as well.

Start learning or implementing following technologies.

**Client side :** 
(For website development you will have to learn these technologies)
HTML5, CSS3, bootstrap x, javascript, jquery, angularjs1.x, angularjs 2(in alpha version), other third party libraries like requirejs, tostarjs,LoDashjs, google apis, angular third party modules and etc.

Note: There are lots of things available other than this. but these are, I guess by far, best things to go on.

As you haven't said you back-end background, I am writing below point by assuming .NET platform still you can go with you own knowing background platform.

**Server-side:**

.NET WEB APIs, Entity framework6+, LinQ, .NET MVC

I have developed many custom solutions with above said technologies and believe me these are the latest platforms to work on together.

I hope it would help to start making website.... (as a front-end developer too ;-))

Answer (score 2):

The effect in the provided website is known as Parallax Effect (Only Scrolling Effect) and it can achieved using Skrollr (https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) plugin. It's very simple to use and modify.

Demo Parallax Effect Link : http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/

So for client side development you can use HTML5,CSS3,jquery and Skrollr plug-in.
And any server side technology will be fine with it. No need to use angularJS.

Answer (score 1):

Single page apps are pretty common now, which means there are heaps of WP themes that would give you a decent base.  In fact, the site you want to emulate used wordpress (according to the builtwith chrome extension).

While the control of an angular app is appealing, I would certainly also consider customizing a wordpress single page theme.